# Conditional regex php with limited length

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

I'm trying to set a regex validation but there's one condition that passes and shouldn't. Seems like I'm missing something. Bellow the regex and what I'm trying to validate. Thanks for any help on this.

My regex:

```
~^(?=([a-z]{2}))[a-z]{2}[0-9]{6}$|(?=([a-z]{1}))[a-z]{1}[0-9]{6}[a-z]{1}$~i
```

Data that should validate (two characters plus 6 digits OR on character plus 6 digits plus one character):

AB123456

A123456B

Data that should not validate. My problem is if a character is added after a valid AB123456 it shouldn't pass.

AB123456A

A123456AB

Comment: use :- `(?=([a-z]{2}))^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{6}$|(?=([a-z]{1}))^[a-z]{1}[0-9]{6}[a-z]{1}$`

Comment: or :- `^(?:(?=([a-z]{2}))[a-z]{2}[0-9]{6}$|(?=([a-z]{1}))[a-z]{1}[0-9]{6}[a-z]{1})$`..you are using anchors wrongly

Comment: What's wrong with using `^([a-z]{2}\d{6}|[a-z]\d{6}[a-z])$`?

Comment: one more thing:- does the characters need to be in first or last? because if its not the case then you regex is wrong

Comment: Thanks rock321987 The second one works perfectly.

Comment: The first one will also work

Comment: yes, both of them work. Thanks a lot for the valuable help.

Comment: what about cases like `A123B57`? should it be valid(i think it should)

Answer (score 2):

When you need to match multiple characters with a regex, you should use limiting quantifiers - and you did. However, when you need to **restrict the length to N characters matched, you should use zero width assertions.

Since your problem is matching entire strings, you need the *anchors*: `^` and `$` (end of string). When validating, I'd rather recommend `\A` instead of `^` and `\z` (that only matches at the end of the string) instead of `$` (that may match before the last newline).

Note you do not need conditional expressions, you need *grouping*.

```
  /\A[a-z](?:[a-z]\d{6}|\d{6}[a-z])\z/
```

Pattern details:

- `\A` - start of string anchor
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase letter
- `(?:[a-z]\d{6}|\d{6}[a-z])` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `[a-z]` - a lowercase letter
  - `\d{6}` - six digits

    or
  - `\d{6}` - six digits
  - `[a-z]` - a lowercase letter
- `\z` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the help and detailed explanation. Very helpful.

Comment: I would add that grouping isn't essential in this case.  After you strip out all the unneeded junk from the OP's regex, the only thing really wrong with it is a missing start anchor (`^`) in the second branch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating this.

You want to match two similar patterns. You can do clever look-behinds/aheads and stuff like that, but what you want in this particular case is much more easily solved by simply matching the patterns separately:

```
/(?:[a-z]{2}\d{6})|(?:[a-z]\d{6}[a-z])/
```

Comment: Thanks Sverri, some of the comments above solved the problem I was having. I was really near it. Thanks

Comment: Your pattern is false since it isn't anchored.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Then anchor it.